# Last frame of EXOPlayer is black when show VAST ads

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer

I use the exoplayer to play the vast ads. After the video end, I switch the app to background and when I restart the app, the video had been destroy(the screen is black). How to make it always present.
I had used silenceMediaSource, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The SilenceMediaSource with a single period consisting of silent raw audio of a given duration and content is expected to show no new frame.

You can try set `app:surface_type="texture_view"`, and `((TextureView)playerView.getVideoSurfaceView()).getBitmap()` get last frame to make the screen not blank.